# Why isn't PHP continuing to run through these urls?

Tags: php, json, foreach, screen-scraping

I have the following PHP. Basically, I'm getting similar data from multiple pages of a website (the current number of homeruns from a website that has a bunch of baseball player profiles). The JSON that I'm bringing in has all of the URLs to all of the different profiles that I'm looking to grab from, and so I need PHP to run through the URLs and grab the data. However, the following PHP only gets the info from the very first URL. I'm probably making a stupid mistake. Can anyone see why it's not going through all the URLs?

```
        include('simple_html_dom.php');

        $json = file_get_contents("http://example.com/homeruns.json");

        $elements = json_decode($json);

        foreach ($elements as $element){
                $html = new simple_html_dom();
                $html->load_file($element->profileurl);
                $currenthomeruns = $html->find('.homeruns .current',0);
                echo $element->name, " currently has the following number of homeruns: ", strip_tags($currenthomeruns); 
                return $html;
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure `$elements` has multiple records that are different? Sometimes little things like that get you. At first glance you code looks sound.

Comment: The $elements, which is the JSON, contains 60ish entries at the moment, all in the form `{ "name":"exampleName","profileurl":"exampleURL" }`

Comment: Disregard my comment as I didn't see your return, which was the real issue.

Answer (score 3):

Wait... You are using return $html. Why? Return is going to break out of your function, thus stopping your foreach.

If you are indeed trying to get the `$html` out of your function for ALL of the elements, you should push each `$html` into an array and then return that array after the loop.

Comment: Hm, if I get rid of the return, I get the following: `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /home/username/public_html/simple_html_dom.php on line 1333`

Comment: Looks like we've solved one question, and it's time for you to ask another about that issue. What is line 1333 by the way? My guess is this one: `$html->load_file($element->profileurl);`

Answer (score 0):

Because you `return`. `return` leaves the current method, function, or script, which includes every loop. With PHP5.5 you can use `yield` to let the function behaves like an generator, but this is definitely out of scope for now.

Comment: Took me too long to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your braces are off, you return at the very end of the loop so the loop will never iterate.